# ORDER BY Month, Year DESC is not working in SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have `table` with date field and I am converting it into **Month**, **Year**, **Day** (3 separate `columns`). It is working fine But I need to order the result by month and year in Descending order.

Here is my query :-

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(
    "select count(*) as TotalCount, tDate, " +
        "sum(case when type = '1' then Amount else 0 end) \"Income\", " +
        "sum(case when type = '2' then Amount else 0 end) \"Expenses\", " +
        "(sum(case when type = '1' then Amount else 0 end) - sum(case when type = '2' then Amount else 0 end)) \"Profit\", " +
        "strftime('%d', tDate) as DayPart, " +
        "strftime('%m', tDate) as MonthPart, " +
        "strftime('%Y', tDate) as YearPart " +
        "from library " +
        "group by MonthPart, YearPart Order by YearPart,MonthPart DESC", 
    null
);
```

It is display in Descending order but only with MonthPart not with both YearPart and MonthPart. Please help.

Comment: Do not store the parts of a date. Store it as one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the answer :-

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery(
    "select count(*) as TotalCount, tDate, " +
            "sum(case when type = '1' then Amount else 0 end) \"Income\", " +
            "sum(case when type = '2' then Amount else 0 end) \"Expenses\", " +
            "(sum(case when type = '1' then Amount else 0 end) - sum(case when type = '2' then Amount else 0 end)) \"Profit\", " +
            "strftime('%d', tDate) as DayPart, " +
            "strftime('%m', tDate) as MonthPart, " +
            "strftime('%Y', tDate) as YearPart " +
            "from library " +
            "group by MonthPart, YearPart ORDER BY date(tDate) DESC", 
    null
);
```